# Why does my RPC call return "Connection refused"?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, rpc

I have a view-only wallet opened, and from another terminal, I try to run the [getbalance](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/wallet-rpc#getbalance) example from the [Wallet RPC documentation](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/wallet-rpc). However, I get a `Connection refused` error:

```
mac:~ user$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18082/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"getbalance"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:18082; Connection refused
```

This is on macOS (Mavericks). Anyone knows why? Should I start the wallet with extra parameters?

Comment: Are you really really sure you ran the wallet in RPC mode (--bind-port 18082) ?

Comment: I tried those, i.e. adding `--rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --rpc-bind-port 18082`, but then I get: `Error: Wallet password not set.` when starting `monero-wallet-cli`. This is a view-only wallet with an empty password. **Update:** getting the same error when doing this for a regular wallet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall, RPC is disabled by default, and needs to be explicitly enabled when running the wallet.

I tried it out and got it working by using the command:

```
monero-wallet-cli --restricted-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18082 --wallet-file <wallet path here> --password <wallet password here>
```

The program will then listen and wait for rpc commands sent to it on 127.0.0.1 . The command in your post should then work.

Comment: The above works. The thing I was missing is **`--password ""` or `--password-file <empty-password-file>`**. I have to say this isn't very obvious from the syntax, although the error message should have rung a bell. Also, I would have expected `--rpc-bind-ip <ip>` to be enough, but it is really `--rpc-bind-port <port>` that is necessary. No idea how to accept the default port if you need to specify the parameter anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe for wallet RPC calls you need to set the --user-agent field now. So, when you launch the wallet in RPC mode (you need to set --rpc-bind-port 18082, as user36303 mentioned), you need to set the --user-agent to be some string of your choice. This is in response to the vulnerability disclosed here:
https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/advisories/csrf-vulnerability-allows-for-remote-compromise-of-monero-wallets/

Then, when you make the RPC call you need to set the User-Agent field of the http header to whatever you set it on the command line when launching monero-wallet-cli.

It looks like from the error message that maybe you're not binding an rpc-port though, and the connection is just being refused because monero-wallet-cli isn't listening on that (or any) port.