# Started monerod on the command line in ubuntu, how to connect to it via the gui?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui

I started the monerod in the command line so I can see the daemon output, but how do I connect to this daemon using the gui? Or should I just start the daemon in the gui instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a `monerod` from the same directory as the GUI, the GUI will automatically connect to it. Doing so will enable you to use the GUI with a local daemon and to see the daemon output. In sum, you should perform the following steps on Linux / Mac OS X:

1. Browse to the directory you extracted the GUI binaries to.
2. Open a new terminal.
3. Type `./monerod`.
4. Open another terminal.
5. Type `./start-gui.sh` (Linux). On Mac OS X you should be able to double click on `monero-wallet-gui`.

On Windows the steps are similar. That is:

1. Browse to the directory you extracted the GUI binaries to.
2. Double click on `monerod.exe`.
3. Double click on `monero-wallet-gui.exe`.

---

I am not entirely sure if the GUI will also connect to a daemon that is started from a different directory, but I think it will.

Comment: A different directory is fine, but ip address (`localhost` or `127.0.0.1`) & port number need to be correct and the daemon needs to enable RPC of course :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have not used the GUI because I could not get my wallet to sync correctly.  This was the first GUI released - I have not tried another GUI release since.

However, from what I remember you only need to launch the GUI and a daemon starts automatically for you.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Letting the GUI start *its own* `monerod` is the easiest, but you can also configure the GUI to connect to a local or remote `monerod`.  It should connect to a local `monerod` automatically (at IP address `127.0.0.1` and port `18081`) if not, you can check your GUI configuration, make sure the daemon is [accepting RPC connections](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2042/why-does-my-rpc-call-return-connection-refused/2060#2060), etc.

More info about ports here: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/635/1023